# Is there a way to rewrite $L = \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{v-4 \times N}-1}{4} \right\rceil$ without the ceiling function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$L = \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{v-4 \times N}-1}{4} \right\rceil$$

This is a line in my program but I cannot get ceil() to work in GMP, so I'd like to approach this mathematically and just rewrite it so it doesn't need ceil().

Comment: What are $v$ and $N$?  Fractions, integers?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Integers

Comment: Does floor work for you?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, floor is fine -- ceil is the only problem

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: ceil(x) = - floor(-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the floor with the difference of the desired quantity and a sufficiently large integer.  In particular here we know:

$$ v > \frac{\sqrt{v-4 \times N}-1}{4} $$

Therefore:

$$ L = \left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{v-4 \times N}-1}{4} \right\rceil = v - \left\lfloor v - \frac{\sqrt{v-4 \times N}-1}{4} \right\rfloor $$

'Nuff said?  There are other ways to do it, but you have $v$ on hand and this is probably the fewest additional operations (and avoids any case logic).  Certainly worth a comment in the code so you don't have a long moment of confusion months down the road...